# AutoMapper IValueResolver: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I want to use IValueResolver in AutoMapper to map two class, and one value will be take from HttpRequest Context, so I want to use IValueResolver

```
CreateMap<Dto, ViewModel>().ForMember(x=>x.MemberID, opt=>opt.Mapfrom<SpecialResolver>())
```

and Resolver is simple

```
public string Resolve(ViewModel viewModel, Dto dto, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
{
  return "test";
}
```

inside startup class i put this:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

but every time I map them for MemberID will throw out error say IServiceProvider been disposed.
so how to make these work? I tried inject this SpecialResolver in startup but also not work. BTW, I'm use .net core 3.0

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu this one I already put inside startup class, I use services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

Comment: You must be doing smth wrong. See [here](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityCore/blob/master/src/ContosoUniversityCore/Startup.cs) a working example.

Comment: @BeiBeiZHU Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the ***actual*** problem.

Comment: @Nkosi Actually I want to inject SpecialResovler into Automapper, before .net core2,2, they suppose work no problem, but after that .net core team removed IServiceProvider, so Now project cant initial SpecialResolver and inject into AutoMapper, I also try services.addTransit<SpecialResolver>() but also not work.

Comment: @BeiBeiZHU show more code e.g. how you inject the SpecialResolver. You can also show what did work in .NET Core 2.2 and how are you trying to achieve the same in .NET Core 3.0. Without the code, there is not much we can do.

Comment: @Prolog I follow this article https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51043.asp-net-core-automapper-handling-profile-dependencies-using-custom-value-resolvers.aspx, but it not work in .net 3.0. hope this will help u understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm strongly convinced that a bug has crept in your code somewhere and hence your problems. On my side, everything works just fine. I tried to recrete what you are trying to do, based on your question and comments. It will surely differ more or less, but you should be able to grasp the idea and get it going on your own.

I'm starting with a mapping profile, where I'm explicitly specifying usage of `HttpContextValueResolver` for `MemberId` property of `ViewModel` class:

```cs
public class MyMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MyMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Dto, ViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.MemberId, opt => opt.MapFrom<HttpContextValueResolver>());
    }
}
```

Then the value resolver:

```cs
public class HttpContextValueResolver : IValueResolver<Dto, ViewModel, string>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public HttpContextValueResolver(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string Resolve(Dto source, ViewModel destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Obtain whatever you need from HTTP context.
        // Warning! HTTP context may be null.

        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Path;
    }
}
```

To acess HttpContext outside a controller I used a dedicated for that purpose service called `IHttpContextAccessor`. Read more about it in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

It isn't automatically available, so I need to register it in `Startup` alongside with the AutoMapper:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Take notice that registering AutoMapper while passing just one type (of Startup), requires that all mapping profiles need to be in the same assembly (project) as the Startup. With mapping profiles in more than one assembly, you need to specify those assemblies or types with a suitable overload of the `AddAutoMapper()` method.

And finally usage in an example controller:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public HomeController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var source = new Dto
        {
            MemberID = "123",
        };
        var result = mapper.Map<ViewModel>(source);

        return View();
    }
}
```

And here are the dto and view model I used:

```cs
public class Dto
{
    public string MemberID { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public string MemberId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Prolog, thanks, finally I know why, our project create a helper class and use that as singleton...

Comment: Glad I could help :)